# useContext values undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm still trying to grasp use of the `useContext()` hook.

I have the following code;

**App.js**

```
const initialPlayerStatus = {
    playerHealth: 5,
    playerCoins: 0,
    playerMoves: 0,
    currentLevel: 1,
}
const PlayerStatusContext = React.createContext(null);
export const usePlayerStatus = () => useContext(PlayerStatusContext);


export default () => {
    const [gameState, setGameState] = useState("MainMenu");
    const [playerStatus, setPlayerStatus] = useState(initialPlayerStatus);
    const updatePlayerStatus = newPlayerStatus => setPlayerStatus(newPlayerStatus);
    const GameComponent = APP_COMPONENTS[gameState];

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <PlayerStatusContext.Provider value={playerStatus, updatePlayerStatus} >
                {GameComponent}
            </PlayerStatusContext.Provider>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

And **GameComponent**

```
export default () => {
    const {playerStatus, updatePlayerStatus} = usePlayerStatus();
    console.log(playerStatus);
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <button onClick={() => {
                console.log(playerStatus)
            }}>Log status</button>

            <button onClick={() => {
                updatePlayerStatus({
                    playerHealth: 6,
                    playerCoins: 1,
                    playerMoves: 1,
                    currentLevel: 2,
                })
            }}>Update Test</button>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

However, the first button returns undefined and the second returns a `updatePlayerStatus` is not a function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by the value that you're injecting into the `Provider`. Consider the following change from:

`<PlayerStatusContext.Provider value={playerStatus, updatePlayerStatus}>`

to:

`<PlayerStatusContext.Provider value={{playerStatus, updatePlayerStatus}}>`

Notice the extra set of `{` and `}` around the value passed to the `value` prop. By doing this, you're combining the `playerStatus` object and `updatePlayerStatus` function into a single `value` that is passed into the provider. This combined value can then be properly destructured by the value returned by your `usePlayerStatus()` hook.

Hope that helps!